# Oracle Version 10 - Do we need anything 'special' to run analytic functions

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, analytic-functions

We're going to be deploying some code to a client who is using Oracle version 10.  Some of our code uses Oracle analytic functions ([LAG](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/analytical/lag.html) in particular).  Is there anything special that needs to be installed/allowed permissiosn/etc. for the code using the analytic functions to execute correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  Analytic functions are just "there" when you've installed the database.

Comment: In General, when installing anOracle Database almost all features are installed and available for you to be used, even the ones that require additional liceses, e.g., partitoning option. Oracle does not restrict the usage of features or check the licese - you are responsible for havig the correct licenses for all features you use -- But the analytic functions are standard functionality and are covered by any oracle license.